# Blogger.com: How to show upcoming posts(scheduled posts)?

Tags: blogger

How can we display upcoming posts in bl;ogger.com/blogspot.com?
These upcoming posts are nothing but future scheduled posts. For example, i have scheduled a post for next week. I want to show my readers that this scheduled post gonna be published shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, no, you can't. The **scheduled** and **draft** posts are both need **Author** level to be displayed (meaning only the blog author/admin can view it).

If you want to inform your user about the scheduled post(s) publication, here's two options that you can try :

1. Add **Text widget**. Write an announcement there.
2. Publish a post that you will use to show an announcement, set the publication date far to the past, let's say 27 June 2001 (it's needed just so the post is not displayed on the homepage). Add a **Featured Post widget** and select that post.